# Filter by regex example

Tags: regex, google-chrome-devtools

Could anyone provide an example of a regex filter for the Google Chrome Developer toolbar?

I especially need exclusion. I've tried many regexes, but somehow they don't seem to work:

[image]

Comment: Would kill one IE user for an answer on this one

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It turned out that Google Chrome actually didn't support this until early 2015, [see Google Code issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=375633&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=375633). With newer versions it works great, for example excluding everything that contains `banners`:

```
/^(?!.*?banners)/
```

Comment: Ah, just found this is/was [a bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/cdJCK5tVqW8)

Comment: Recently, the Regex checkbox (and the ability to filter by regular expressions) seems to have vanished. Is anyone else seeing that?

Comment: @Dave, I just upgraded from 55.0.2883.87 m to 56.0.2924.87 (Windows 7) and it's still there. Note that, as always, you first need to enable filtering (hit the filter icon next to "preserve log") to see the filter toolbar, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#filtering_the_console_output Do you even see the selectors for All, Errors, Warnings and all?

Comment: @Arjan, Thanks. I'm on Version 57.0.2987.21 beta (64-bit). It is missing in that build, and is apparently being replaced in 58 by a "proper" implementation using the `/regex/` format. Grab a copy of Canary to see it in action, if you like.

Comment: @Dave, quite funny as I came to this question to figure out how to use `^` in the regular expressions (for the start-of-line; seems to have no effect, or I don't know what exactly it's looking in). And then I read your first comment. Good to know the current implementation is apparently not a proper regex, which is better than me losing my mind ;-)

Comment: It's coming, it would appear… They seem to fiddle around with the regex searching in the console & networks tabs every couple of versions. I hope that the version currently in Canary (currently on 58) is reliable and stable.

Comment: could you explain why this regex ^(?!.*?banners) doesn't work without ^ at the beginning? (I understand that ^ is start of expression in regex)

Answer (score 37):

It's possible -- at least in Chrome 58 Dev. You just need to wrap your regex with forward-slashes: `/my-regex-string/`

For example, this is one I'm currently using: `/^(.(?!fallback font))+$/`

It successfully filters out any messages that contain the substring "fallback font".

**EDIT**

Something else to note is that if you want to use the `^` (caret) symbol to search from the start of the log message, you have to first match the "fileName.js?someUrlParam:lineNumber " part of the string.

That is to say, the regex is matching against not just the log message, but also the stack-entry for the line which made the log.

So this is the regex I use to match all log messages where the actual message starts with "Dog":

```
/^.+?:[0-9]+ Dog/
```

Comment: Btw: None of the answers work reliably for me anymore, in Chrome 79 -- including the exact patterns listed. Since they worked before, I'll need to do more testing to see what's causing some to fail.

Answer (score 18):

The negative or exclusion case is much easier to write and think about when using the DevTool's native syntax. To provide the exclusion logic you need, simply use this:

```
-/app/ -/some\sother\sregex/
```

The "-" prior to the regex makes the result negative.

Answer (score -4):

Your expression should not contain the forward slashes and /s, these are not needed for crafting a filter.

I believe your regex should finally read:

```
!(appl)
```

Depending on what exactly you want to filter.
The regex above will filter out all lines without the string "appl" in them.

edit: apparently exclusion is not supported?

Comment: Hmm you are right, regexes seem to work okay but exclusion does not :/