# Is it possible to filter Chrome/Firebug network panel by regular expression?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, analytics, developer-tools

In [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158916/filter-by-regex-example) there is a screenshot showing a similar feature to what I want to do, but the regular expression checkbox is not there in my Chrome Developer Tools.

I want a regex filter for the network tab, not for the console output.

For example, to filter requests going out to three ad providers, I'd like to be able to put something like (ad1|ad2|ad3) in the network filter. Or for analytics, (_utm|omtrdc|scorecard).

[Also related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077976/is-it-possible-to-search-with-regular-expressions-within-chromes-developer-cons)

Comment: I see it in my chrome dev tools. I switch to the Network tab, type some regex in the box, and tick the regex checkbox next to it. I'm using Chrome `52.0.2743.116 m`; maybe you've got an old version?

Comment: You may have to use slashes at either end so it regexes instead of just searches: `/(ad1|ad2|ad3)/`

Answer (score 0):

I was analyzing my website, which has alot of images loaded.

Here is what i am using all the time to exclude image from the network listing

To Exclude `jpg` only

```
^((?!.jpg).)*$
```

To exclude jpeg, png, jpg

```
^((?!.jpeg|png|jpg).)*$
```

[image]