# Why the character ^ is required in an regex ^(?!.*?spam) to filter strings?

Tags: regex

I try to filter strings, that don't contain word "spam".
I use the regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158916/filter-by-regex-example)!

But I can't understand why I need the symbol ^ at the start of expression. I know that it signs the start of regex but I do not understand why it doesn't work without ^ in my case?

UPD. All the answers hereunder are very usefull. 
It's completely clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Because without it, the final character of the string alone will match the pattern, eg `m` in `spam` (or `am` in `spam`, or `pam` in `spam`). You need to make sure that `spam` doesn't occur *anywhere* in the string, rather than letting the start of the tested substring forward-track.

Comment: It's easy to see that without `^` regexp matches any single character in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it helped you (green tick on the left).

Comment: It is not required in many situations, as a lot of validation tasks are performed with methods that only test the input string against the regex *once*. However, it is best practice, as the regex might be used with methods that search for all occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

The regex `(?!.*?spam)` matches a position in a string that is *not* followed by something matching `.*?spam`.

Every single string has such a position, because if nothing else, the very end of the string is certainly not followed by anything matching `.*?spam`.

So every single string contains a match for the regex `(?!.*?spam)`.

The anchor `^` in `^(?!.*?spam)` restricts the regex, so that it only matches strings where the very *beginning* of the string isn't followed by anything matching `.*?spam` — i.e., strings that don't contain `spam` at all (or anywhere in the first line, at least, depending on whether `.` matches newlines).

Answer (score 2):

The lookahead is a zero-width assertion (that is, it ensures a **position** in your string). In your case it is a negative lookahead making sure that not "zero more characters, followed by the word spam" are following. This is true for a couple of positions in your string, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/p25MCW/1) *without* the anchor.

*With* the anchor the matching process starts right at the very beginning, so the whole string is analyzed, see [**the altered demo**](https://regex101.com/r/p25MCW/2) on regex101.com as well.